# How can I have differents "ERRORS 1064 (42000)" for the same sql file?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When I try to import a dump in my database, it returns :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 30001: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 25.

The sql file has been exported with MySQL 5.1.2.

The strange thing is that each time I try to import, the error line indicated changes ! It can be line "30001" as above, or line "400", "57000"... without I change the .sql file !

The content of the sql file imported is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geonames2` (  
`geonameid` int(10)    unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT    '',   
`ansiname` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
`alternatenames`    varchar(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   
`latitude` double NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',   
`longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',      
`feature_class` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,   
`feature_code` varchar(10)    DEFAULT NULL,   
`country_code` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,   
`cc2`    varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,   
`admin1_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',      
`admin2_code` varchar(80) DEFAULT '',   
`admin3_code` varchar(20)    DEFAULT '',   
`admin4_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',   
`population`    bigint(11) DEFAULT '0',   
`elevation` int(11) DEFAULT '0',      
`gtopo30` int(11) DEFAULT '0',   
`timezone` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,    
`modification_date` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',   
PRIMARY KEY    (`geonameid`)  ) CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, the INSERT part (which creates the problem I think):

```
INSERT INTO `geonames2` (`geonameid`, `name`, `ansiname`, `alternatenames`,      `latitude`, `longitude`, `feature_class`, `feature_code`, `country_code`, `cc2`, `admin1_code`, `admin2_code`, `admin3_code`, `admin4_code`, `population`, `elevation`, `gtopo30`, `timezone`, `modification_date`)     
     VALUES (1024032, 'Île Glorieuse', 'Ile Glorieuse', 'Glorieuse,Ile Glorieuse,Île Glorieuse', -11.55, 47.3, 'T', 'ISL', 'FR', '', '00', '', '', '', 0, 0, -9999, 'Europe/Paris', '2012-01-18'),
     (1024034, 'Île du Lys', 'Ile du Lys', 'Ile du Lise,Ile du Lys,Le Lys,Île du Lys', -11.5, 47.36667, 'T', 'ISL', 'FR', '', '00', '', '', '', 0, 0, -9999, 'Europe/Paris', '2012-01-18'),
     ...
     ...
     still 137, 000 rows !
     ...
     ...
     (2968290, 'Villes-sur-Auzon', 'Villes-sur-Auzon', 'Villes,Villes-sur-Auzon', 44.05669, 5.2343, 'P', 'PPL', 'FR', '', 'B8', '84', '843', '84148', 1100, 0, 295, 'Europe/Paris', '2011-07-19');
```

I spent my night to discover the problem in the INSERT part but I still don't see the problem... I need a fresh pair of eyes to help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine.. I tried to dig out the error, But There is no error in your code. Might be a problem with your DB Tool. instead dumping just copy and paste the content in your tool's sql tab. It works fine, you can see my effort [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4518/1) at sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The script can be very big and it can be very difficult to find the error. The error line connected to one of the hundreds or thousands statements.

Try to run the script using Sql Document in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition). Open your SQL-file in Sql Document and press F5 (Execute), the error will be underlined. In Professional version syntax errors will be checked on document opening.